# Как лучше распечатать/сохранить текст с веб-странички?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, веб-программирование

Создал страничку. В некотором div разместил информацию, которую нужно вывести на печать / сохранить в удобном формате для печати, например, DOC и другие.

Как это лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Обычно делается отдельное окно/вкладка, где отображается содержимое, которое нужно распечатать и из JS вызывается метод print()

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем корректный вопрос - вывести на печать и сохранить в док- две разные задачи. Вывести на печать можно и с помощью css - @media print {} и создавайте стили для печати, а вот для док и пдф нужна библиотека jquery

Answer (score -1):

Используйте плагин для jQuery [printPage](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-printPage-plugin)
для печати